# In VBA, how do I amend a specific line of a .txt file?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, text

I want to amend a specific line (example: line #5) of a .txt file using VBA.

How would I be able to do so?

Comment: Please read this article about using StackOverflow. Following the guidelines here will result in better answers and less frustration: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Start by breaking the problem down in to parts. Research each part one by one. Put it all together and then come back when you have code and are stuck. Maybe if you try you will figure it out before getting stuck!

Comment: I have broken it down.

All I want is the line of code where I can amend a given line number (say line N) of a text file.

Comment: You need to split the .txt file into string array by lines and then amend it, this is more then one line of bode, it's you need to get the text then change it and then save is...

Answer (score 0):

Below is some VBA code that reads in a text file in one chunk, splits it into separate lines into an array, replaces the text on the fifth line (the array is 0-based, so the elements are 0, 1, 2, 3, **4**, 5,.....), and then joins it back together to write it out to a text file. It then finally deletes the original file, and renames the output file.

```
Sub sAlterFile()
    Dim strInFile As String
    Dim strOutFile As String
    Dim intInFile As Integer
    Dim intOutFile As Integer
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim aData() As String
    intInFile = FreeFile
    strInFile = "C:\test\sample.txt"
    Open strInFile For Input As intInFile
    strInput = Input(LOF(intInFile), intInFile)
    aData() = Split(strInput, vbCrLf)
    aData(LBound(aData) + 4) = "new"
    intOutFile = FreeFile
    strOutFile = "C:\test\amended.txt"
    Open strOutFile For Output As intOutFile
    Print #intOutFile, Join(aData(), vbCrLf)
    Close #intInFile
    Close #intOutFile
    Kill strInFile
    Name strOutFile As strInFile
End Sub
```

Regards,